# MySQL: Ideas for facility booking system Database

Tags: php, mysql, updatecheck

I want to get ideas for database design for a facility booking system. Here is what is in my mind:

```
Bookings:
- id
- facility
- Start Datetime
- End Datetime
```

The reason I'm asking is, during booking process I need to check if the facility is available or not.

Is the below method appropriate or there is better method for this checking?

```
if ( ( (newStartDatetime >= bookedStartDateTime) && (newStartDatetime < bookedEndDateTime) ) || ( (newEndDatetime > bookedStartDateTime) && (newEndDatetime =< bookedEndDateTime) ) ) {
    // The facility is booked
}
```

Comment: Time is linear (still). Therefore you only need to check that a) x_start <= y_end and that b) x_end >= y_start

Comment: Thanks, this really made my validation a lot easier.